# No PCLInt warnings are displayed

Tags: jenkins, compiler-warnings, pc-lint

I have given proper path to PCLint error log in jenkins job for PCLint compiler-Scan workspace files.

After executing job i got below error message:

> Successfully parsed file D:........\abc.lint with 0 unique
>   warnings and 0 duplicates.

Skipping warnings blame since Git is the only supported SCM up to now.

> abc.lint file contain PClint error, still jenkin not showing any
>   PCLint warnings.

Comment: The default output format of PC-lint is different from what most compilers produce. So you might want to use e.g. the option --format="%(%f:%l:%c:%) %t %n %m" to adjust the output format to something that Jenkins can understand.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example what Jenkins can understand. We are getting following error in the output (.lint) file but Jenkins is not able to detect any warnings/errors
.\TestAppl_Alarm_Fault_Seq1\Config\inc\Test.h  39  Error 46: field type should be _Bool, unsigned int or signed int [MISRA 2012 Rule 6.1, required]